# Thunderbird - How do I download IMAP folders?

Tags: thunderbird

I just reinstalled Thunderbird for an existing IMAP account.  Thunderbird shows only my inbox.  In webmail I can see all my old folders for that email account.

How do I tell Thunderbird to download all of the IMAP folders to my local machine?

Comment: It would be better to ask this question on superuser.